# upload library not working in module I am building

Tags: add-on-development, module, file-uploads, uploads

I've been stuck trying to upload a file in a module I am buidling.

I've tried using the EE instance and now I am trying the CI instance.

I've checked permission settings and those are fine for the directory I am trying to upload to.

I set the form type to use the form_open_multipart

Here is my upload function that does not want to work:

```
function upload_file()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();

    $file = $this->EE->input->post('userfile');

    $config['upload_path'] = './images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $this->CI->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->CI->upload->do_upload($file) )
        print 'could not upload file';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that should help you out.

1) You should be using the EE instance. Normally you to the get_instance() in the constructor of your module and make it available as a class variable.

2) The do_upload method accepts a string with the name of the file upload field, not the value of the posted field.

Your code should look somehting like this

```
// Configure the upload class
$config['upload_path'] = './images/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$this->EE->load->library('upload', $config);

// Error checking
if ( ! $this->EE->upload->do_upload('file_field_name'))
{
    $data = array(
      'error' => $this->EE->upload->display_errors()
    );

}
// No problems so do our processing
else
{
    // Store the info about the uploaded file
    $upload_data = $this->EE->upload->data();
}
```

This was taken directly from a module I wrote that uploads files, so should work for you with some minor adjustments.